# How to remove white space below recyclerView in CoordiantorLayout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, toolbar

friends. For several days I have been working whith the problem - how to remove the white space at bottom of screen. The toolbar is created in the fragment, and for unknown reasons RecyclerView leave white space at the bottom, like toolbar size. Help me, please.

[image]
`

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/main.appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="600dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:background="@color/grey"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:elevation="5dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:contentScrim="@color/bir"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <SurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/main.surface"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            />


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:text="@string/app_name"
                    android:textColor="@color/red"
                    android:textSize="80dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:typeface="serif" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="Stream &apos;em All!"
                    android:id="@+id/textView4"
                    android:textColor="@color/red"
                    android:textSize="50dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="67dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="67dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="91dp"
                    android:typeface="serif" />
            </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            android:elevation="5dp" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>



</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/stream_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_float"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/main.appbar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
    app:layout_behavior="com.example.shpp.videoapp.Utils.FABBehavior"
    android:id="@+id/start_button"
    android:elevation="5dp"/>
```

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (mView != null)
        return mView;
    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.welcome_fragment, null);
    findViews();
    return mView;
}

private void findViews() {
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) mView.findViewById(R.id.stream_list);
    mSurface = (SurfaceView) mView.findViewById(R.id.main_surface);
    mFloatButton = (FloatingActionButton) mView.findViewById(R.id.start_button);
    mAppBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) mView.findViewById(R.id.main_appbar);
}

private void initViews() {
    mFloatButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            NotificationCenter.getInstance().generateEvent(Event.GO_TO_STREAM, null);
        }
    });

    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getContext());
    StreamListDataProvider mStreamListDataProvider = new StreamListDataProvider(this.getContext());
    StreamListAdapter mArapter = new StreamListAdapter(this.getContext(), mStreamListDataProvider);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mArapter);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder = mSurface.getHolder();
    HolderCallback holderCallback = new HolderCallback();
    mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(holderCallback);
    mSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}


@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mAppBarLayout.setExpanded(false);
    initViews();
    mCamera = Camera.open(ZERO);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mCamera.stopPreview();
    mCamera.release();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
}`
```

Comment: why height is 600dp of app bar layout?

Comment: mm, oh, it not a top layout, it expand from parent CoordinatorLayout..

Comment: FloatingActionButton displaying or not?

Comment: swap collapsing toolbar and appbarlayout.Coordinatorlayout should be the root element.

Comment: it in coordinatorLayout, but not working